# Nokogiri Namespace confusion

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Using this snippet of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" version="2.0" unique-identifier="p9781449617424">
    <metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
        <dc:title>Essentials of Health Care Finance</dc:title>
    </metadata>
</package>
```

How would I get the value of the tag `dc:title` with Nokogiri?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use XPath and register the namespace:

```
doc.xpath('//dc:title', 'dc' => 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/')
```